# Array of floats throws "incomplete type is not allowed"

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm still fairly new to C++, so maybe its a very simple error I made here.
I wanted to initialize a private float array in one of my classes, like this.

```
float firstVect[] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
```

but firstVect is underlined with the explanation of incomplete type.
On the other hand two lines below the float array i have an int array looking like this:

```
int normalNumberOfDigits[]= {0,0,0};
```

The compile does not complain about the int array but only about the float array. Why?

Full code of my class:

```
class DataFilter
{

public:
   int filterMovement(float vect3[3])
   {
       //TBD
   }

private:

   float firstVect[] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
   int initialized = 0;
   int normalNumberOfDigits[]= {0,0,0};
   int determinNumberOfDigits(float testValue)
   {
     //TBD
   }
};
```

Comment: I take issue with your assertion the compiler is comfortable with the `int[]` initializer, [as that isn't the case](http://ideone.com/v71ePG).

Comment: If you look at actual compiled code, you'll see both the int and the float parts are errors: https://godbolt.org/g/XA1KuQ

Comment: You are right, when I clicked build this line was also marked as invalid, although only in the build errors section and not, as usual, in the code by a red underlining.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Compiling with a modern version of clang++](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UYwsJw7hjtDbDxpj) makes your mistake obvious:

> **error: array bound cannot be deduced from an in-class initializer**

You need to explicitly specify the size of the arrays *(if you want to use a C-style array)* in your class initialization:

```
class DataFilter
{
   // ...
   float firstVect[3] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
   int initialized = 0;
   int normalNumberOfDigits[3]= {0,0,0};
   // ...
};
```

---

> *"The compile does not complain about the int array but only about the float array. Why?"*

Compiling with a modern version of g++ makes this obvious as well:

> **error: flexible array member `DataFilter::normalNumberOfDigits` not at end of `class DataFilter`**

When you declare an array without an explicit size, the compiler thinks that it is a [*flexible array*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), which is a C-only feature. It seems to be allowed in C++ as a non-standard g++ extension.

Answer (score 2):

Non-static data members must have complete type, i.e. if they are arrays  they must contain the array size. The size *cannot* be inferred from any initializers, because initializers are a) optional and b) not really part of the class definition, but rather implicitly part of all *constructor* function definitions.

Simple fix:

```
 float firstVect[3] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
 //             ^^^
```

To clarify the explanation a bit: A class definition with default member initializer like this:

```
struct Foo
{
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
};
```

is conceptually the same as:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo();
    int a[3];
};

Foo::Foo() : a{1, 2, 3} {}
```

You see now that the initializer is not really a part of the class definition, and thus cannot be used to deduce the array size.

A more extreme example is this:

```
struct Bar
{
    Bar(int) : a{1, 2, 3} {}
    Bar(float): a{1, 1} {}
    Bar() = default;

    int a[???] = {4, 4, 4, 4, 4};
};
```

What should the type of `Bar::a` be here?

Answer (score 1):

Clang reports a clearer error:

```
fatal error: array bound cannot be deduced from an in-class initializer
```

You have to explicitly size your arrays:

```
class DataFilter
{
    // ...
private:
   float firstVect[3] = {0.0f,0.0f,0.0f};
   int normalNumberOfDigits[3]= {0,0,0};
};
```